Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Italian Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Significato e origine dell'espressione "la testa come un cesto"

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the appropriate translation for "d'ogn'intorno"?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Sull'uso della preposizione "presso"

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Avete il mio libro o Hai il mio libro?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Cosa significa "spicchi" in questo contesto?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


Perché si dice "dormire saporitamente"?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


"Precisamente" versus "appunto"

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)


Perché ci sono tante interiezioni che contengono la "h"?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)


Baltimora è l'unica città nordamericana col nome italianizzato?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)


È corretta l'espressione "Avrei piacere di..."?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


The image of a growing site:


One aspect that I find wonderful about this site is that, whenever I've asked a question, I've always got an answer. This isn't true for other StackExchange sites, where my questions remain frequently unanswered. 
